# How to load modal dialog box while loading the home page of website?

Tags: javascript, magento

How to show modal dialog box when my website's home page loads, in a dialog box there are two fields one for email address and another for password and also options for signup and forgot password, I am using magento application, I am trying write onLoad() event under body tag of my first page that loads but couldn't see the change on browser. All I want is when my website home page loads, dialog box should appear immediately so that only registered users can see the content inside my web.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You want a modal dialog box to hide content only registered users should be able to see? Not good idea... . Everybody can remove this box.

Comment: in all modern browsers I have full control of the client code, I can even manipulate it live within the developer tools (for the most part). Client Side security is busted. Sorry but i think you need to re evaluate your security

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/He9Lc/1/)

And here you can find how to make use of it http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Just add div

```
<div id="example" class="xyz" title="This is my title">
    I'm in a dialog!
</div>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#example").dialog({modal: true});
});​
```

Comment: don't forget to reference JQuery and JQuery UI for this :-) as in the jsfiddle is shown.

Comment: @RodyvanSambeek-Thanks for that just I was trying to answer the other guy and forgot to mention it.Updated now  :)